# Align text next to image1 and under image2 HTML

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've tried all the possibilities that I've found so far but I couldn't manage to make the text (and the second image) look like it should.

I guess it's just no big deal that I'm doing wrong, but I just can't figure it out what. Any help would be very much appreciated!

This is my html:

```
<div class="cf">
            <div><img src="https://www....></div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://www...>
                <p>Some text1</p>
                <p>
                    ABC <br />
                    D EF G
                </p>
           </div>
</div>
```

And this is my .css file:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the left image, use `float:left`, and use `padding-right` to add a gap between the image and the text.

Create a new `.clear` div which will clear your floats and prevent any further elements floating.

```css
.cf {
  
}
.cf .left-item {
  float:left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.cf .right-item img + p {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.clear {
  overflow:hidden;
  clear:both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cf">
    <div class="left-item"><img src="https://www.ebner.cc/typo3temp/images/WAPPEN4-3d.png" width="52" height="61" alt=""></div>
    <div class="right-item">
        <img src="https://www.ebner.cc/fileadmin/redakteur/image/EBNER-Trademark.png" width="63" height="12" alt="EBNER">
        <p>Industrieofenbau GmbH</p>
        <p>Bearer of the <br />Austrian State Coat of Arm</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
.cf .cf-title {
    margin: 0 0 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.cf-desc {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.cf p {
    color: #666;
}
.cf .content {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.cf {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cf">
            <div><img src="https://www.ebner.cc/typo3temp/images/WAPPEN4-3d.png" width="52" height="61" alt=""></div>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="https://www.ebner.cc/fileadmin/redakteur/image/EBNER-Trademark.png" width="63" height="12" alt="EBNER">
                <p class="cf-title">Industrieofenbau GmbH</p>
                <p class="cf-desc">
                    Bearer of the <br />
                    Austrian State Coat of Arm
                </p>
           </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
.cf:before,
    .cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
    }
    
    .cf:after {
    clear: both;
    }
    
    .cf > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .cf {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding-right: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="cf">
            <div><img src="https://www.ebner.cc/typo3temp/images/WAPPEN4-3d.png" height="96" alt=""></div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://www.ebner.cc/fileadmin/redakteur/image/EBNER-Trademark.png" width="63" height="12" alt="EBNER">
                <p style="margin: 0;">Industrieofenbau GmbH</p>
                <p>
                    Bearer of the <br />
                    Austrian State Coat of Arm
                </p>
           </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is more an issue of your font being too big. The way everything's "blocked" is absolutely fine.

Try adding the below to your CSS and start tweaking the font size and family to your liking.

```
.cf p {
  margin:0 0 5px 0;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

and also add `padding-right:10px` (or whatever value you want) to `.cf > div`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7smkaqj9/