# How to position text on the right side of an image

Tags: css

I want to place my paragraph text on the right side of an image, just like in this mockup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBOjP.jpg

I aligned the text by setting the display of the parent to flex and it now looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaUAT.jpg

The text is dropping on a new line on each word, how can I make it look like in the mockup?

````css
.zodiac-info {
  width: 500px;
}

.blog-entry-name {
  padding: 0px;
}

.zodiac-paragraph {
 color: black;
 width: 200px;
}

.blog-entry-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

.blog-entry {
  display: flex;
}
```
````

```html
<section class="zodiac-info">
    <div class="blog-entry-container">
    <input  type="search" class="search-box fa fa-search" placeholder="  &#xf002 search">
    <div class="blog-entry">
      <img src="../assets/images/test-image.jpg" alt="test image" class="test-img">
      <p class="zodiac-paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-entry">
        <img src="../assets/images/test-image.jpg" alt="test image" class="test-img">
        <p class="zodiac-paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-entry">
          <img src="../assets/images/test-image.jpg" alt="test image" class="test-img">
          <p class="zodiac-paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309972/align-text-next-to-image1-and-under-image2-html/54310161#54310161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just update your code with few CSS changes. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.zodiac-info {
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.blog-entry {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.blog-entry img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.blog-detail {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.blog-detail label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.blog-detail p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.blog-detail small {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<section class="zodiac-info">
  <div class="blog-entry-container">
    <input  type="search" class="search-box fa fa-search" placeholder="  &#xf002 search">
    <div class="blog-entry">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6bz4.gif" alt="test image" class="test-img">
      <div class="blog-detail">
        <label>Heading 1</label>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <small>Date: 02-04-2019</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-entry">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6bz4.gif" alt="test image" class="test-img">
      <div class="blog-detail">
        <label>Heading 1</label>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <small>Date: 02-04-2019</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-entry">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6bz4.gif" alt="test image" class="test-img">
      <div class="blog-detail">
        <label>Heading 1</label>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <small>Date: 02-04-2019</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `float: left` and `float: right` to move the text and image all the way.

Comment: Tried it but it does not affect it at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use **css grid** or **flexbox**. You use flexbox, so:

```css
.zodiac-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


.blog-entry {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}


.blog-entry-name {
  padding: 0px;
}

.zodiac-paragraph {
 color: black;
}

.blog-entry img {
 width: 180px;
 height: 180px;
 min-height: 180px;
 object-fit: cover;
 flex: 1;
}

p.zodiac-paragraph {
   padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
   margin: 0;
}

.blog-entry-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<section class="zodiac-info">
    <div class="blog-entry-container">
    <input  type="search" class="search-box fa fa-search" placeholder="  &#xf002 search">
    <div class="blog-entry">
      <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*eXIBeNlLhz4Pe6vDrYkXLQ.png" alt="test image" class="test-img"></p>
      <p class="zodiac-paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-entry">
        <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*eXIBeNlLhz4Pe6vDrYkXLQ.png"  alt="test image" class="test-img">
        <p class="zodiac-paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-entry">
          <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*eXIBeNlLhz4Pe6vDrYkXLQ.png" alt="test image" class="test-img">
          <p class="zodiac-paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both the image and the paragraph are in the same div, you can use absolute and relative positioning.

```
.blog-entry {
    position: relative;
}

.zodiac-paragraph, .test-img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Try to look at this codepen if this solves your prob.

https://codepen.io/jls314/pen/EJjVzK

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

---

```
.blog-entry{display: in-line-block}
```